# Source for studying data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, tree, n-ary-tree

Does anybody know a good source where to study data structures? In particular i am looking for trees and graphs. I've already tried geekforgeeks but i wonder if there is something else as good as it.

Thank's.

Comment: You have some specific requirement or is this just a general query? If you have specific requirements then please add them to your question. That way you will get specific suggestions that will be useful for that problem. This will assist other visitors to SO with that requirement. i.e. You have a particular data-structure that you need information about?

Comment: Search on Amazon for books on data structures and read the customer reviews. Order what seems to be the best one. Even in this day and age, books are richer sources for study than online tutorials.

Comment: Which programming language you prefer ?

Answer (score 0):

For algorithms on trees and graphs you can prefer "Thomas H. Cormen Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition, and for coding practice you can prefer InterviewBit or Leetcode(coding platforms) and apart from that, you must try geeksforgeeks
the link for book is 
http://ressources.unisciel.fr/algoprog/s00aaroot/aa00module1/res/%5BCormen-AL2011%5DIntroduction_To_Algorithms-A3.pdf